# PyQt5 clipboard doesn't work with clr

Tags: .net, pyqt, clipboard, python.net, pythonnet

I builded a program that runs a PyQt5 gui and reads C# data from an external dll
When I `from clr import AddReference`the QApplication.clipboard doesn't seems to work.

There are easy work around to solve this but I wanted to know how does this prevents the clipboard from working.

And this problem happens when I only import clr

This clr is install from the pythonnet project

Any information will be great.

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/439